Busemann-Petty type problems on complex vector spaces
We recently published an article on Busemann-Petty type problems (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.05630). As we experienced several times that as soon as an article is published, no updates/corrections/... are given any more leading to follow-up mistakes, we would like to open here a central spot to collect all errata/public comments/discussion on our article.
In particular, we would welcome

any report on errors (including typos in relevant formulas and constants) in our article
comments and discussion on the results of the article (including references to follow-up articles which extend/improve our results).

This is the first time we try this and our main motivation is to increase quality and transparency. If you have any suggestions for a better way to do this, please let us know.

this is not really suitable for MO, which is a site for a specific question, which can then receive a definitive answer; a platform that allows for comments of arXiv papers is https://scirate.com (although at present it mainly has topics in quantum information)
